# Jenkins: update SCM without triggering a build?

Tags: build, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

We have an SCM-controlled project that polls a repo every several minutes. Overall the workflow is great but occasionally I need to push the new changes to the server's repository without triggering a build in Jenkins (for various reasons: long builds, minor changes, concurrent commits etc).

I have already set up a quiet period, and sometimes I just start and stop the build (which is awkward), so the Jenkins pulls the changes and does not trigger the build later.

So, is there a plugin of any sort that allows either:

- Manually cancel the future build (before it's triggered by SCM poller)
- Manually update the project's SCM repo without triggering a build?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have many solutions to do this :

1. Instead of polling your SCM and trigger a build on change, you can do it another way. You can make your SCM decide if the commit should trigger a job or not. [Have a look there for an example](http://fatalfailure.wordpress.com/2011/12/28/triggering-jenkins-jobs-from-the-scm-push-to-avoid-the-evil-polling/)
2. You could try to use the "Excluded Commit comments" property in Subversion extended properties of your job, this way, you could avoid to trigger builds on "useless commits".

Comment: Cédric, you're right, both options are good and reasonable. It's a pity that MercurialSCM doesn't yet support a similar concept. As to the first one, there are a few issues: you must have an access to the SCM server (which I don't) and you have to know that the commit will be minor a priori. We also constantly add new projects to Jenkins, so configuring SCM for every new project might be tiresome.

Comment: After some thinking and reading Kohsuke's opinion on this (http://kohsuke.org/2011/12/01/polling-must-die-triggering-jenkins-builds-from-a-git-hook/) I have decided to give a server-wide post-commit hook a try. For Mercurial there is a guide here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mercurial+Plugin

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at that: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PollSCM+Plugin

you should configure the build trigger as "Build periodically" (without "Pool SCM" trigger) only and i think that might do the job

Comment: Thanks for the link, eyossi. The plugin already does most of the job, I'll try it and get back.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea (not necessarily a better one, but it may better suit your tastes): use [Run Condition Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Run+Condition+Plugin). Make the rest of your build conditional on a parameter (let's name it *DO_BUILD*). Set that parameter to *TRUE* by default. If you need to commit something without triggering the build set *DO_BUILD* default to *FALSE*.

A variation on the same idea: you do your polling in one job (*Trigger*) that calls your main job via [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) in a build step. That build step is then can be conditioned upon a parameter. Note that in this case you will either have to use the same custom workspace for both builds, or do a manual check out (say, in a shell build step) in the main job.